# What does (float)(par4 >> 16 & 255) / 255.0F; mean?

Tags: java, hex, bit-manipulation

I found this line of code: `this.red = (float)(par4 >> 16 & 255) / 255.0F;` where red has been declared as a `float`.

I am trying to understand what it does, especially because the full code is:

```
this.red = (float)(par4 >> 16 & 255) / 255.0F;
this.blue = (float)(par4 >> 8 & 255) / 255.0F;
this.green = (float)(par4 & 255) / 255.0F;
this.alpha = (float)(par4 >> 24 & 255) / 255.0F;
GL11.glColor4f(this.red, this.blue, this.green, this.alpha);
```

so I'm guessing this somehow uses different locations of an int (`par4`) to color text. `par4` is equal to `553648127` in this case.

What do those four lines mean, notably the `>> 16 & 25`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RGB with alpha channel (usually known as [RGBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) or aRGB) are four bytes packed into one integer.

```
AAAAAAAARRRRRRRRBBBBBBBBGGGGGGGG   // the original par4, each char represents one bit.
                                   // where ARBG stands for alpha, red, blue and green bit.
```

The shift and and operator are used to retrieve each individual byte.  For example, `par4 >> 16 & 255` is first right-shifting the integer 16 bits such that the original 3rd byte is located at base, and the `255` is served as mask to extract only one byte.

And `par4 >> 16` will right-shift the original byte 16 bits;

```
0000000000000000AAAAAAAARRRRRRRR
```

Finally, applying `&255`, which is `00000000000000000000000011111111` in bit-representation, will mask the last 8 bits:

```
  0000000000000000AAAAAAAARRRRRRRR
& 00000000000000000000000011111111
= 000000000000000000000000RRRRRRRR
```

This gives you the red byte.

Comment: alright, so it would do something like:
`553648127` -> `005536481` -> `1` ?

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder, I must be drunk :p

Comment: @Shef: When dealing with bitshifts and bitwise AND operations, it's best to look them in binary, not decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized that when translating the number to binary I get `0b100000111111111111111111111111` Which makes more sense to work with.

Answer (score 4):

`>>` is the right-bit-shift operator. This is more easily seen in binary:

```
b1000 >> 3 = b0001
```

You see how it moved the bits right.

`&` is the bitwise AND operator. The result of `x & y` will be a value with **only** the bits in `x` and `y` that were both on being on.

```
b1  & b1  = b1
b1  & b0  = b0
b0  & b1  = b0
b11 & b01 = b01
```

So

```
this.red = (float)(par4 >> 16 & 255) / 255.0F;
```

...takes the value from `par4` and shifts the bits right 16 bits to move the "red" value to the rightmost part. Then it masks off anything other than the rightmost byte of that. Then it divides the value (which must be in the range `0` to `255`, inclusive) by `255` as a float, resulting in a floating point value between `0.0` and `1` telling us how "red" the color was.

And similarly for blue and green.

Then it uses the same mechanism to determine how strong the alpha channel (transparency) is.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise-anding with 255 (0b11111111) discards all bits from an integer except the eight least significant bits. If you right-shift first, you can access eight-bit groups from other areas of that integer.

Answer (score 0):

`par4` seems to define a color with RGB value and alpha as an integer with 4 bytes.

So the 4 bytes are singled out by shifting the bytes "lower" bytes to the right with the `>>` operator and masking out the "higher" bytes with the `& 255`.
Afterwards the byte value is normalized to a float value between 0.0 and 1.0 via the `/ 255.0f`.

If the 4 bytes in our integer are like AARRGGBB, where AA, RR, GG, BB each denote a byte and you e.g. want to single out the red color, you first shift away the green and blue bytes with `>> 16`, which will leave you with an integer 0000AARR, then you mask out the alpha with the `& 255`, which will leave you with an integer 00000000RR, where RR is now 1 byte (2 half-bytes) with values between 0 and 255, which you finally transform to a float between 0.0 and 1.0 by division with the `/ 255.0f`.